# Error when adding duplicate on array on angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular-js so I created a mini app where the user adds elements in an array and the values of the array are displayed above. The app works fine but crashes when a value that already exists in the array is added.

here's the source code.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"></p>
    <a ng-click='add(firstName)' >click me</a>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}
    </ul>
    {{msg}}
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.add = function(arg) {
            alert("adding:"+arg);
            $scope.names.push(arg);
        }

        $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here's the console error when for example I add twice the name John:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=x%20in%20names&p1=string%3AJohn&p2=John
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
>       at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:280:375
>       at Object.fn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:130:77)
>       at r.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:131:149)
>       at r.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:78)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:126)
>       at If (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:367)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.Hf.d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:314)

When this error occurs the function still works, as the alert pops up but the value of the input is not added in the array. I didn't implemented any js-fiddle because there it works fine. I use chrome browser

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=x%20in%20names&p1=string%3AJohn&p2=John at Error... If you follow this link you could read answer to your question. I recommend to check links which angular gives to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace ng-repeat with:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">{{x}}
</ul>
```

AngularJS tracks by default by the value of the elements, if you have duplicates it fails. $index corresponds to the $index of `names[$index]` used by AngularJS when looping the array.

Comment: It works! Thanks I will accept your answer as soon as possible. Any idea why in a fiddle I made ng-repeat works fine?

Comment: @JmRag: Because you didnt have a duplicate ?

Comment: Of course I had. I used the same test case

Comment: @JmRag: check the angularjs version of the jsfiddle, and it seems weird